# T-SQL Date difference greater than an integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables: Name, and Birthday. I need to get Names of people who are over 18, but I cannot manually enter a date.

```
UserID = int
Name = varchar(50)
Birthday = Date


UserID Name  UserID Birthday
----------- -----------------
  1    ABC    1     1997-05-15
  2    DEF    2     1997-09-21
  3    GHI    3     2011-02-01
```

I currently have this:

```
select u.UserID
from tbl_Name as u
join tbl_Birthday as b on u.UserId=b.UserID
where Birthday < '1997-08-22';
```

I tried changing the last line to the following and it still didn't work:

```
where datediff(year, birthday, convert(date, getdate())) > 18;
where Birthday - convert(date,getdate()) > 18;
```

Edit: I mixed up startdate and enddate in DATEDIFF, but this gives me problems with people who are 18 (born in 1997).

Edit 2: Made question more clear by specifying that a date cannot be manually entered.

Edit 3: Changed birthday dates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate exact date difference in years using SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145404/calculate-exact-date-difference-in-years-using-sql)

Comment: DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate) there is three parameter and u pass only 2.

Comment: Why would you write something like CONVERT(date, GETDATE())? GETDATE() is a date!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not do date math on the `Birthday` column. That requires calculating the expression for every row in the table! Instead, do the math on the other side of the equality or inequality.

If your birth dates are stored with no time portion:

```
WHERE Birthday <= DateAdd(year, -18, GetDate)
```

If they are stored with a time portion that can be set to other than midnight, by convention a person is 18 on the date of their birthday, so:

```
WHERE Birthday < DateAdd(year, -18, Convert(date, GetDate() + 1))
```

Note: subtracting `datetime` values in SQL Server yields the number of days apart, explaining why one of your expressions was not working correctly (you treated it like years).

Comment: If I am not wrong this will give you the list of people UNDER 18, which is not what is requested!

Answer (score 0):

```
  where DATEADD(YY,18,Birthday) >= getdate()
```

Comment: I tested a birthday in 1997-08-04 and 1997-08-31 and the results were the same (people over 18 on August 22, 2015 should have been born before August 22, 1997).

Comment: I just tried `day(getdate()) - day(Birthday)  > 18*365` and that didn't work...drats.

Comment: I don't want to enter a date though.  What happens if I need to run the query a few months later?  I don't want to manually change the input to a date that would make it work.

Comment: I think he meant by the literal date the `Birthday` column.

Comment: @Peter : I just gave an example. You will obviously have to use your column name. :)

Comment: @ErikE : Yes, that is what i meant. :)

Comment: Answer went to @ErikE as it was posted first =) Thanks for all the help!

Comment: This requires an expression to be calculated on every row in the table. That's not good for performance!

Comment: Someone has down voted, may I please know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query if u want to try to retrive that person who are above 18.

```
     where DATEDIFF(YEAR,birthday,GETDATE())>18
```

Comment: This is wrong. How old is a person born 2000-12-31 on 2018-1-1? Certainly not 18, since he just turned 17 the day before!

Comment: This don't work for people born in the year that makes them 18.  If today is August 22, 2015, people over 18 include those born before August 22, 1997.  If there is a birthday in 1997, say May 15, 1997, this person should be over 18 but this DATEDIFF using YEAR as the datepart doesn't give this result.

Comment: can u shayer your data in sql fiddle,because it working properly in my database.



@Peter

Comment: David Sam don't be silly. It can't be working. Try my example.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( year((Cast (getdate() as date))-year(cast (BirthDay as date)))>18)
begin
select  birthday
end
```