# How to call SQL to show in age from the table of date of birth?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to ask how can I call SQL that show in age from the table of Date of birth?

As I have to call SQL to show the average age of employees who are retired of a company.

[image]

[image]

[image]

my SQL statement:

```
Select AVG (age)
From Employee, Career
Where employee.employee_ID=Career.employee_ID
AND Career.Status =Retired
```

but I don't have the "age table"

Comment: Please edit your question to include the SELECT statement you are trying to use.

Comment: You should also post the table schema

Comment: i couldn't call the table out as my data table is DOB table. 

Select AVG (age)
...

but i dont have age table

Comment: You would have to calculate the age.  Again, please post the table schema for your DOB table.

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: You should also post your Career table since you have included it in your Select statement.

Comment: what i included in my employee table is their DOB, in career table there is employee_ID and their status showing their status, what i want to call in SQL is their average age when they retired

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145404/calculate-exact-date-difference-in-years-using-sql - it shows how to calculate the age from the DOB.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: For Postgres: `select avg(age(dob)) from ...`

Comment: it says undefined function 'age' in expression

Comment: Does it concern anyone else that if the retired people have died, the given solutions consider them to still be aging? Not that the OP has given us any means to address that concern.

Comment: Based on the data, no one have died when they retied. Besides, I need to call SQL to calculate the age of all employees (whole data) instead of just one person.

Answer (score 0):

You were right in using AVG, from there you just need to calculate the age of each person.  You can do it all in one query (and there are many ways, as mentioned in the comments). The age math here is adapted from an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145404/calculate-exact-date-difference-in-years-using-sql)

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(yy, employee.Date_of_Birth, GetDate()) -
        CASE WHEN MONTH(GetDate()) < MONTH(employee.Date_of_Birth) THEN 1
             WHEN MONTH(GetDate()) > MONTH(employee.Date_of_Birth) THEN 0
             WHEN DAY(GetDate()) < DAY(employee.Date_of_Birth) THEN 1
             ELSE 0 END)
FROM Employee
   JOIN Career on employee.employee_ID = Career.employee_ID
      AND Career.Status = 'Retired'
```

(SQL Server here, as the original question did not specify.  Leaving it in case it helps someone)

Comment: thanks for the information, as i have to do the "1" &"0" things in my Part 4 so im trying a more simple way to call SQL in my Part3 which is the question i asked.

Comment: This does exactly what you asked... what did you really need?

Comment: Thank you for the help. However i tried to run it in Access and it doesn't work. Is it not for Access?

Comment: No it is not.  You didn't specify so I wrote it for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT
    AVG(DateDiff("yyyy", employee.Date_of_Birth, Date()) + Int(Format(Date(), "mmdd") < Format(employee.Date_of_Birth, "mmdd")) as AverageAge
FROM Employee
JOIN Career on employee.employee_ID = Career.employee_ID
      AND Career.Status = "Retired"
```

With the logic shamelessly stolen from [here](http://access.mvps.org/access/datetime/date0001.htm)

Comment: Was about to post similar SQL (shamelessly stolen as well).  You could change `Now()` to `Date()`

Comment: Good point @DarrenBartrup-Cook, I've edited my answer accordingly.