# A fractional DATEDIFF for SQLServer?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datediff

Found out something recently (and sure, my fault for not reading the docs) that reasonably horrified me about SQLServer's DATEDIFF function; it counts the number of interval boundaries between the two specified dates.

This means I can ask it for the number of days between `01 Jan 23:57` and `01 Jan 23:59` and it will return 0, but if I ask for the days between `01 Jan 23:59` and `02 Jan 00:01` it will tell me there is 1 day between them. The timespan is the same: 2 minutes, but suddenly one is a difference of 0 days and one is a difference of 1 day

Coming from an Oracle and .Net background I can see I've made a gross error in assuming that DATEDIFF in TSQL worked equivalently (i.e. prepare a timespan and then round it to the specified interval), but what is the alternative?

If I want to find out exactly, with decimal places, how many years there are between 2 dates, how do I do it in SQLServer? I don't want a result from 01 Jan to 31 Dec returning 0 years, but 31 dec 2000 to 01 jan 2002 returning 2 years, because these are gross errors and miles away from the 0.997 and 1.005 (not exact calcs) they should more likely be..

The answer clearly isn't to DATEDIFF the days and divide by 365.0, not only because datediff is routinely "wrong" even for DAYS (as per my 2 minute example) but also because there aren't always 365 days in a year. Same for months -> they aren't always a specified number of intervals long, so it doesn't make sense to take days and divide by 31 (or 30, 29, or 28).. For the same reasons I cannot do simple `(endDateTime - startDateTime)/x` math

Comment: Could you look at answers to this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145404/calculate-exact-date-difference-in-years-using-sql)? There are some methods.

Comment: "but also because there aren't always 365 days in a year". Is the (fractional) number of years between 2017-03-29 and 2017-03-30 greater than the difference between 2000-03-29 and 2000-03-30 in your model, given that the latter was a leap year and was thus slightly longer? Do you really want to take the exact length of all calendar years that span the period into account? Because that's not a pretty calculation. Most folks would just go with the Julian year length of 365.25 days and be done with it.

Comment: As far as .NET background goes -- the difference between two dates is a `TimeSpan`, and it does not have a `TotalYears` property, for good reason. It's unclear how you plan to get your values of 0.997 and 1.005.

Comment: You don't seem to realise that your examples of why these things can't be done in days are exact examples of why this isn't straightforward. What is 0.5 of a month? Or a year? The only exact way to model this sort of circumstances is to record the interval - with the actual start and end dates - rather than trying to produce a single number.

Comment: Re your example about the number of days between 1 Jan 23:59 and 2 Jan 00:01, you are right that there is only 2 minutes between them but in real life the times are on different days (today and tomorrow for instance). So I think the issue boils down to the imprecise nature of what we mean when we refer to number of days between two date/times. For businesses that I have worked in, these events would be classed as being a day apart, but other businesses may consider them as being no days apart as there hasn't been a whole 24 hours between them. Maybe we need some meta language about this :)

Comment: endDateTime - startDateTime will give you a timespan and for your minutes example would give you 1900-01-01 00:02:00.000, From this you can get number of years using Years(enddateTime - startDateTime) etc. Or decode this in code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want accuracy, you can go for minutes when doing the `datediff` and multiply the result accordingly. You can tweak the `@dateFrom` and `@dateTo` to test the outputs with the below code:

```
DECLARE @dateFrom DATETIME, @dateTo DATETIME

SET @dateFrom = '2017-07-01 23:59'
SET @dateTo = '2017-07-02 00:01'

SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @dateFrom, @dateTo) minsDiff

SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @dateFrom, @dateTo) / 60.0 hoursDiff

SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @dateFrom, @dateTo) / 60.0 / 24.0 daysDiff

SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @dateFrom, @dateTo) / 60.0 / 24.0 / 365.25 yearsDiff

SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @dateFrom, @dateTo) / 60.0 / 24.0 / 365.25 * 12 monthsDiff
```

It all depends on what you want to report and what your business logic is. You can do additional queries like so:

```
-- to track a change in days - take off the time portion:
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(@dateFrom AS DATE), CAST(@dateTo AS DATE)) daysDiff
-- to track a change in years - you use the year funtion:
SELECT YEAR(@dateTo) - YEAR(@dateFrom) yearsDiff
```

Comment: I'm not certain that any of this answers the question, as it's all an example of "what I don't want" as cited in the latter paragraphs of the question. `Year(a) - Year(b)` also reports 2 for my `dec 2000 to jan 2002`  example even though it's only 1.005 years

Comment: @CaiusJard it all boils down to your business logic though, I'm just trying to illustrate there are methods available to get the output you desire based on what you want your application to show. Regarding your year query, this from the above posted would give you that value: `SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @dateFrom, @dateTo) / 60.0 / 24.0 / 365.25 yearsDiff`

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** this code does not include DST.

You can also build your own code, which will be calculating difference between dates and put it into function.

```
DECLARE @dateFrom DATETIME, @dateTo DATETIME

SET @dateFrom = '2000-12-31 23:59'
SET @dateTo = '2002-01-02 00:01'


SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR, DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,0,DATEADD(year,1,@dateFrom)),0), DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,0,@dateTo),0))
       + CASE WHEN YEAR(@dateFrom) < YEAR(@dateTo) THEN (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @dateFrom, CAST(YEAR(@dateFrom) AS CHAR(4))+'-12-31 23:59') + 1) / (1.0*DATEDIFF(minute, CAST(YEAR(@dateFrom) AS CHAR(4))+'-01-01 00:00', CAST(YEAR(@dateFrom) AS CHAR(4))+'-12-31 23:59') + 1)
       + (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(YEAR(@dateTo) AS CHAR(4))+'-01-01 00:00',@dateTo ) + 1) / (1.0*DATEDIFF(minute, CAST(YEAR(@dateTo) AS CHAR(4))+'-01-01 00:00', CAST(YEAR(@dateTo) AS CHAR(4))+'-12-31 23:59') + 1)
       ELSE (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@dateFrom, @dateTo) + 1) / (1.0*DATEDIFF(minute, CAST(YEAR(@dateTo) AS CHAR(4))+'-01-01 00:00', CAST(YEAR(@dateTo) AS CHAR(4))+'-12-31 23:59') + 1) END
--Result: 1.002745428591627
```

This code needs comments, so:

`+1` is needed to obtain exact number of minutes between dates.

This is used for calculating how many minutes year has.

```
(1.0*DATEDIFF(minute, CAST(YEAR(@dateTo) AS CHAR(4))+'-01-01 00:00', CAST(YEAR(@dateTo) AS CHAR(4))+'-12-31 23:59') + 1)
```

This give us beginning of the year.

```
DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,0,@dateTo),0)
```

This piece of code is calculating full years between `@dateFrom` and `@dateTo`.

```
DATEDIFF(YEAR, DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,0,DATEADD(year,1,@dateFrom)),0), DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,0,@dateTo),0))
```

This is calculating "partial" years. We are calculating how many minutes left to the end of year.

```
(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @dateFrom, CAST(YEAR(@dateFrom) AS CHAR(4))+'-12-31 23:59') + 1) / (1.0*DATEDIFF(minute, CAST(YEAR(@dateFrom) AS CHAR(4))+'-01-01 00:00', CAST(YEAR(@dateFrom) AS CHAR(4))+'-12-31 23:59') + 1)
```

Similary to what we have above but for `@dateTo`.

```
(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(YEAR(@dateTo) AS CHAR(4))+'-01-01 00:00',@dateTo ) + 1) / (1.0*DATEDIFF(minute, CAST(YEAR(@dateTo) AS CHAR(4))+'-01-01 00:00', CAST(YEAR(@dateTo) AS CHAR(4))+'-12-31 23:59') + 1)
```

Here, we are calculating years when `@dateFrom` and `@dateTo` have the same year part.

```
(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@dateFrom, @dateTo) + 1) / (1.0*DATEDIFF(minute, CAST(YEAR(@dateTo) AS CHAR(4))+'-01-01 00:00', CAST(YEAR(@dateTo) AS CHAR(4))+'-12-31 23:59') + 1)
```

Comment: Want to hear something mean? "What about DST?"

Comment: @JeroenMostert Hah, I didn't think about it. I used this code for calculating, where I didn't have to care about DST, because we weren't using time part. Need to think about it. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: I wasn't seriously suggesting rewriting it to take DST into account, because, even it can be done, it'll be unreasonably difficult. I know of few projects where it would really be necessary to have the exact number of minutes between local times. And where you do, you probably wouldn't want to calculate this back into fractional years, because what good would it be? If you wanted to add or compare periods, you could/should just use the smallest meaningful unit you're dealing with (be it minutes or seconds), in UTC.