# Subtracting dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to convert a PostgreSQL query to a T-SQL query, and I can not get the syntax correct for this PostgreSQL line:

```
ROUND(CAST((CURRENT_DATE - setupdate) AS decimal) /365,1) AS RetentionYears
```

When converting it to T-SQL, I have tried this

```
ROUND(CAST((GETDATE() - setupdate) AS Decimal) / 365, 1) AS RetentionYears
```

But when I run that I get the error

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 43
> The data types datetime and date are incompatible in the subtract operator.

What would be the proper way to write that statement in T-SQL?

Comment: Well! You can use `DATEDIFF()` function to get it done. I believe, you want to retrieve days from them.

Comment: Thanks, I'll toy around with the ``DateDiff()`` function and see what I can get @AT-2017

Comment: Original code has an obvious error surrounding leap years. `DATEDIFF(year,...` may not do what you want as it counts date boundaries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate exact date difference in years using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145404/calculate-exact-date-difference-in-years-using-sql)

Answer (score 3):

You want `datediff()`:

```
DATEDIFF(year, current_timestamp, setupdate) As RetentionYears
```

Answer (score 0):

As other people have mentioned, you should use datediff().

However, if you want to use your query you can cast your setupdate as datetime.

```sql
ROUND(CAST((GETDATE() - CAST(setupdate AS DATETIME)) AS Decimal) / 365, 1) AS RetentionYears
```