# Entity Framework Core check if record is older than 5 years

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to select records that are older than 5 years to archive them.

What I tried is using the `DateDiffYear` function:

```
var projekte = await this.db.Project
        .Where(x => EF.Functions.DateDiffYear(
            x.CreateDate, 
             this.dateTimeProvider.Today) >= 5)
        .ToListAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Unfortunately, this also selects a record with the CreateDate is 2017-08-20 even if today is 2022-08-19 - it only checks the year...

Is there an easy way to calculate this correctly so that it only selects the row if 5 complete years have passed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145404/calculate-exact-date-difference-in-years-using-sql) out. In particular, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36767786/941240) takes specific month/day shifts into account.

Answer (score 2):

```
var fiveYearBeforeToday=DateTime.Today.AddYears(-5);
var projekte = await this.db.Project
            .Where(x => 
                x.CreateDate > fiveYearBeforeToday)
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken)
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
    DateTime maxAge = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5);
    var projekte = await this.db.Project.Where(x => maxAge.CompareTo(x.CreateDate >= 0)).ToList();
```

alternatively using your approach:

```
DateTime maxAge = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5);
var projekte = await this.db.Project
        .Where(x => EF.Functions.DateDiffYear(
            x.CreateDate, maxAge) <= 0)
        .ToListAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```